# "ruach elohim" in Genesis 1.2 translated with "a very strong wind"

Tags: hebrew, midrash, genesis-bereishith

I read, in some biblical forums, the intervention of Israeli Orthodox Jews according to which the most correct translation, in Genesis 1: 2, of "ruach elohim" is "a very strong wind", saying that here "elohim" is to be understood as an absolute superlative (also in this forum some users translate the expression with the similar "a strong wind").

However, I have not understood what are  the specific linguistic and midrashic sources are in support of this interpretation.

I see that the Jewish translations I can read generally don't follow the aforementioned exegesis, but they use this following expressions :

"the Divine Presence" (Tanach Artscroll)

"a wind from God" (JPS 1985)

"the spirit of God" (JPS 1917;English translation by Rav A. J. Rosenberg ;Italian translation by Rav Dario Disegni ).

Targum Onkelos says, if I understood well, "a wind from HaShem" (yud-yud).

It is also true that my compatriot Shadal (Rav Samuel David Luzzatto) translates with "a wind of God, that is, very strong", and, except my mistake, also the famous Jewish philosopher Baruch Spinoza says that "a very strong wind" is the correct translation.

Comment: Though I've never heard this interpretation before, I think this may come from understanding the term "elohim" here in its other meaning. The phrases "elohim" and "el/elim" both refer to greatness, might, strength. These were terms assigned to men in positions of power. When applied to Hashem, they refer to His might and also become names of His. But they are also words with non-divine meanings. I expect that such an interpretation of the phrase is useful in combating the heretical interpretation that some have that claims that the tohu v'vohu and the waters also existed prior to creation.

Comment: Never saw the"very strong wind" translation. Seems kind of odd to me that "elokim" would mean G-d every other time it's used in that chapter and "super duper" in that sentence.

Comment: What is the question here? Different interpreters see it differently.

Comment: @Al Berko Hi Al, the question is what are the linguistic and midrashic sources on which basing this type of translation.

Answer (score 2):

This is the explanation of the Radak and Ralbag. To quote the [Radak](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.1?lang=he&aliyot=0&p2=Ralbag_Beur_HaMilot_on_Torah%2C_Genesis.1.2.2&lang2=en&p3=Radak_on_Genesis.1.2&lang3=en):

> It is also possible that the reason it appears in this mode is because it is such a powerful agent of G’d that it sometimes appears to have Divine force. It is quite common in our use of language that when we want to stress the power of someone or something, we somehow associate it with the name of G’d. In the Book of Jonah the city of Nineveh is thus described as עיר גדולה לאלוקים, (Jonah 3,3) and Psalms 36,7 uses the expression כהררי א-ל, in order to describe towering mountains.

Answer (score -2):

Tikunei Zohar #26, daf 71b top:

> עד דייתי רעיא מהימנא, דאתמר ביה ורוח אלקי"ם מרחפת, דאיהו רוח דמשיח, דאתמר ביה ונחה עליו רוח ה',

...until the Raaya Meheimna (Faithful Shepherd, spirit of Moshe Rabbeinu) comes, of whom it says, *w'ruach-Elokim m'rachefet*, which is **the spirit of Mashiach**, as it says of him (Isa. 11:2): And resting on him, the spirit of H' etc.

Comment: This does not support the translation the OP is looking to support.

Comment: @magicker72 Is he "looking to support" that translation or asking is it legit. I posit the latter and that it's not legit.

Comment: `However, I have not understood what are the specific linguistic and midrashic sources are in support of this interpretation.` seems to be looking for support.